# Get 'backtrace' of an assertion error in ruby unit testing

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, minitest

When creating a helper method for unit testing, the console output of the failure only indicates the line where the actual assertion happened.

```
# Just an example method.
def test_equal(a, b)
  assert_equal a, b # Error indicates this line
end

test_equal(1, 2) # I'd like to know this line
test_equal(2, 3)
```

Is there a way of showing something like a "backtrace" or provide more context for these assertion errors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've analyzed this matter further and stumbled across minitest's method [Assertion.location](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/master/lib/minitest.rb#L633). There, it goes through the backtrace (failed assertions result in exceptions of type `Minitest::Assertion < Exception`), reverses it and looks for methods starting with one of the following keywords:

- `assert`
- `refute`
- `flunk`
- `pass`
- `fail`
- `raise`
- `must`
- `wont`

Therefore, the example in the original question should look like the following:

```
# Just an example method.
def assert_my_equal(a, b)
  assert_equal a, b # Error indicates this line
end

assert_my_equal(1, 2) # This is the line number indicated in the failure report
assert_my_equal(2, 3)
```

This also explains why the Rails-specific assertion methods behave correctly: They start with `assert_`.